# can my programs access more than 4GB of memory?

Tags: python, 64-bit

if I run python on a 64bit machine with a 64bit operating system, will my programs be able to access the full range of memory? I.e. Could I build a list with 10billion entries, assuming I had enough RAM? If not, are there other programming languages that would allow this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to be sure that Python has been built as a 64 bit application. For example, on Win64 you'll be able to run the 32bit build of Python.exe but it won't get the benefits of the 64 bit environment as Windows will run it in a 32bit sandbox.

Comment: Does that mean I would be better off running it on Linux? Or can I build a 64 bit Windows exe for Python?

Comment: There's already one available at http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.0.1/python-3.0.1.amd64.msi
They've called the install amd64 as recognition of the fact that AMD created the 64bit instruction set. The install will work on Intel and AMD CPUs

Comment: There's also a Python 2.6.1 64bit version at http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.6.1/python-2.6.1.amd64.msi

Answer (score 3):

The language python itself has no such restrictions, but perhaps your operating system or your python runtime (pypy, cpython, jython) could have such restrictions.

What combination of python runtime and OS do you want to use?

Comment: actually, I don't mind. I have an application that I'm working on now (partly in Matlab and partly in Python) which is running into memory limitations, and I want to plan a move to 64bit. I wasn't sure whether Python would be the right language, but from that you say, it sounds like it should be ok.